# libvirtd kvm networking on Centos5.4

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, qemu, libvirt

I've got KVM installed on CentOS 5.4, and am attempting to set up a virtual network to allow each VM to communicate with services on the host, namely DHCP to allow PXE boot installations.
I'm having some serious problems getting the network to work correctly.  I suspect there's some subtlety missing in my configuration, but everything is set up according to the defaults, and I'd expect it to work.

Here's the config for the network, domain, and some stuff about the host.

Network definition: http://pastebin.com/m48c28c5e

Host definition: http://pastebin.com/m58dbf605

Host info (brctl, ifconfig, iptables): http://pastebin.com/m20e6b47b

DHCPd Config: http://pastebin.com/m610e7f44

I'm steadily running out of ideas..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out in the end.  The trick is to ignore all the KVM networking nonsense.  Create a bridge with brctl and then tell the KVM guest to use that as a bridge device.

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='00:a0:01:00:00:03'/>
  <source bridge='virbr0'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
</interface>
```

And it works..